# Why isn't the sequencer repeating the AutoPage?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-presentation-language

Got Actual:

Text1 --> Text2 --> Text3

Expected: (wanted it to repeat)

Text1 --> Text2 --> Text3 --> Text1 --> Text2 --> Text3 --> Text1 --> ...

Apl Code: https://apl.ninja/document/Borghild/why-sequencer-not-repeating-6sts

```
{
  "type": "APL",
  "version": "1.8",
  "settings": {},
  "theme": "dark",
  "import": [
    {
      "name": "alexa-layouts",
      "version": "1.5.0"
    }
  ],
  "mainTemplate": {
    "parameters": [
      "payload"
    ],
    "items": [
      {
        "type": "Pager",
        "id": "myPager",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "Text",
            "text": "Text1"
          },
          {
            "type": "Text",
            "text": "Text2"
          },
          {
            "type": "Text",
            "text": "Text3"
          }
        ],
        "onMount": [
          {
            "type": "Sequential",
            "sequencer": "mySequencer",
            "repeatCount": 99999,
            "commands": [
              {
                "type": "AutoPage",
                "componentId": "myPager",
                "duration": 500
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in addition to autoPage I need to add also setPage just after autoPage like this, and now it repeats.

```
            "commands": [
              {
                "type": "AutoPage",
                "componentId": "myPager",
                "duration": 500
              },
              {
                "type": "SetPage",
                "componentId": "myPager",
                "value": 0
              }
            ]
```